# consuming a map from configmap to springboot application

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, configmap, configurationproperties

I have added a map in my values.yaml file like below

```
defaultview:
  journey:
    ce5f164c-ae0f-11e7-9220-c7137b83fb6a: 45
    abc: -1
    pqr: 30
```

I read this property in configmap like below

```
defaultview.journey: {{ .Values.defaultview.journey }}
```

When I check configmap I see entry like below in cm

```
defaultview.journey:
----
map[abc:-1 ce5f164c-ae0f-11e7-9220-c7137b83fb6a:45 pqr:30]
```

Java class is trying to bind this property into a Map<String,Integer> like below

```
import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Data
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "defaultview")
public class JourneyViewConfig {

    private Map<String, Integer> Journey = new HashMap<>();

}
```

I see error thrown while spring boot startup

```
Failed to bind properties under 'defaultview.journey' to java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Integer>:\\n\\n    Property: defaultview.journey\\n    Value: \\\"map[abc:-1 ce5f164c-ae0f-11e7-9220-c7137b83fb6a:45 pqr:30]\\\"\\n    Origin: \\\"defaultview.journey\\\" from property source \\\"<cm name>\\\"\\n    Reason: org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Integer>
```

Is there a way to inject Map directly from configmap to spring boot?

Edit 1:
I am able to read the values in map by adding this **dirty code**

```
private Map<String, Integer> parseConfigValue(String configValue) {
    Map<String, Integer> resultMap = new HashMap<>();

    String trimmedInput = configValue.trim();
    if (trimmedInput.startsWith("map[")) {
        trimmedInput = trimmedInput.substring(4, trimmedInput.length() - 1);
        String[] pairs = trimmedInput.split(" ");

        for (String pair : pairs) {
            String[] keyValue = pair.split(":");
            if (keyValue.length == 2) {
                String key = keyValue[0].trim();
                Integer value = Integer.parseInt(keyValue[1].trim());
                resultMap.put(key, value);
            }
        }
```

Is there a more subtle way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is problematic:

```
defaultview.journey: {{ .Values.defaultview.journey }}
```

You're trying to include a structured variable as a simple string, so this is resulting in a ConfigMap that looks like:

```
data:
  defaultview.journey_broken: map[abc:-1 ce5f164c-ae0f-11e7-9220-c7137b83fb6a:45 pqr:30]
```

That's not useful, as it's neither valid YAML nor JSON and probably isn't what your application is expecting.

You're going to need to use the `toYaml` function to render your structured variable as a block of YAML text. For example:

```
data:
  defaultview.journey: |
{{ indent 4 (.Values.defaultview.journey | toYaml) }}
```

Which results in:

```
data:
  defaultview.journey: |
    abc: -1
    ce5f164c-ae0f-11e7-9220-c7137b83fb6a: 45
    pqr: 30
```